# How can I use selected value (not model value) as Post Parameter In Razor View?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, viewmodel

I am posing a model back to my controller,

How every I want the user to select the country from a drop down, So I pass this to the view in a separate list:

Controller GET:

```
public static List<String> provinces = new List<String>() { "Eastern Cape", "Free State", "Gauteng", "KwaZulu-Natal", "Limpopo", "Mpumalanga", "Northern Cape", "North West", "Western Cape" };
    public static List<String> countries = new List<String>() { "South Africa" };

  public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.Provinces = provinces.Select(x =>
                              new SelectListItem()
                              {
                                  Text = x.ToString()
                              });
        ViewBag.Countries = countries.Select(x =>
                               new SelectListItem()
                               {
                                   Text = x.ToString()
                               });
        return View();
    }
```

Now I display the Drop down in the View:

```
   ....   
 <p>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Province, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("Provinces", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Province, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </p>

    <p>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Country, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("Countries",null , htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Country, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </p>
  ....
```

and here is my View Model:

```
public class RadioNetwork
{           
    public int NetworkIdentifier { get; set; }
    public string CommonName { get; set; }
    public string RepeaterName { get; set; }
    public string StartCode { get; set; }
    public string Frequency { get; set; }
    public string Area { get; set; }
    public string Province { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }                 
}
```

So I have discovered where the issue is. But I donot know how to solve it.

I need the form to take the selected Value of my DropDown and not of the model?

Because when I receive the View Model in the POST Controller the provence and Country are `Null'

```
   [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Include = "NetworkIdentifier,CommonName,RepeaterName,StartCode,Frequency,Area,Province,Country")] RadioNetwork radioNetwork)
    {
```

Comment: For reference, you don't need the `[Bind]` attribute at all, simply use `Create(RadioNetwork radioNetwork)` as it will achieve the same result as `[Bind]` in this case.

Comment: Is it just Used for cases when you only want to include particular values?

Comment: True, but you were including all the values in the class by the looks of it. To be honest, I never use `[Bind]` or its counterpart `[Exclude]`. It just makes things harder to understand and follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model isn't binding properly because you're using the wrong method to render the DropDownLists. The fields in your form bind to your model according to the `name` attribute, and the `DropDownList()` method renders a field without that attribute. When you want form fields to bind properly to a model, you should always take care to use methods that end in `For` so you don't have to worry about the model binding.

You're doing

```
@Html.DropDownList("Countries",null , htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

You should be doing

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Country, (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Countries, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Also, your lists should be:

```
ViewBag.Provinces = provinces.Select(x =>
                          new SelectListItem()
                          {
                              Text = x.ToString(),
                              Value = x.ToString()
                          }).ToList();
```

P.S. You don't need any of the bind stuff at all.

Comment: I have copied what you suggested. however I am getting an error message on the DisplayDropDownFor()  saying: ` Model.RadioNetworks has no applicable method namded 'dropdownListFor', Exntension Mehtods cannot be dynamically dispatched.`

Comment: See my edit to the "What you should be doing" bit. Also, what version of ASP.NET MVC are you using?

Comment: Thanks, and I am using MVC 5

Comment: OMW you are a genius. Thank you so much, I have been struggling for hours. Its working now :)

Comment: @Zapnologica Next time, check the HTML that is rendered. If the field that isn't binding is missing its name attribute or has the wrong name attribute (should be the same as the property you want to map it to on your model) there's your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
@Html.DropDownList(m => m.Province, (SelectList)ViewBag.Provinces, ...
```

This will bind the selected Province to your model